# How to do incremental computation with big data

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, distributed-computing, nosql

I have a big data set (about 10T), and I need **do some hourly updates** on these **key-value pairs** (0.4B keys) with some incremental data (about 300G per hour), e.g. append some events to a user's event list. Also I need remove data that's out-of-date to maintain the size of the data set. Although the incremental data is small (compared to the data set), **most of keys in data set will be updated**.

By now, I have two solution, however, neither is good enough.

1. **hadoop**. Take the data set and the incremental data as input of mapper, and do the updates in reducer. However, since the data set it too large, it's not a good idea to distribute and shuffle the whole data set every hour. We also consider doing daily updates (i.e. only update the data set when all incremental data is ready). But it takes more than one day to finish the whole mapreduce job...
2. **nosql**. Keep the data set in a distributed nosql database (in our case, rocksdb), and do the updates with the database. Since most of keys will be updated, we CANNOT do the update with the 'Get-Update-Set' pattern (too many keys, and random read is slow). Luckily, keys in rocksdb are ordered, we can make the incremental data sorted, and do a merge sort with the data set in rocksdb. In this way, we only need do sequential read on rocksdb, which is fast. **Compared to the hadoop solution, we don't need shuffle the large data set hourly**. Also, we can merge several hours' incremental data before updating the data set, so that we don't need scan the whole data set hourly.

The second solution works good when the data set is NOT that big (i.e. 3T). However, when the data set grows to 10T, there's too much disk read and write, and the system works bad.

I'm wondering is there any good solution for incremental computation for big data, or is there any nosql for batch computation? I really don't think hadoop is a good choice for incremental computation, especially when the incremental data is much smaller than the data set.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Can we clarify a couple of points?  (1) You say you're updating most of the keys -- but what you describe is extending the values.  Are you only updating the records (values) or are you actually altering the keys themselves?  This would eliminate any stably predictive serialization.  (2) You're adding 300G/hr; do you reclaim a comparable amount of space with the clean-up?

Comment: How large will the data set grow within your current event horizon?  Can you solve the problem with faster & larger hardware (sometimes the only solution)?  Are you doing any analysis on the data, or is this data-base only?

Comment: Did you consider SPARK?

Comment: @Prune (1) I need extend values of most keys, and occasionally, add or remove some keys. (2) you can take the value as a list, and I need keep the newest N elements of the list. So when the system goes stable (i.e  the list of each key is full), if I add 300G/hr, I also need clean-up 300G/hr. (3) When the system goes stable, the data set should grow up to 10T. (4) By now, I don't have faster & larger hardware. (5) the data seems don't have any special feature, and I've already did some compression on the data.

Comment: @sunrise76 I'm not familiar with Spark. Is it suitable for incremental computing?

Comment: For 10TB of data, Spark is good solution. Hadoop is ruled out for data updates.

Comment: I suspect that the Hadoop latency will give you troubles; the situation you describe is write-bound.  Spark has an up-front latency penalty, but works well thereafter for large data sets.  Since you're updating everything, I expect Spark is the way to go.  However, do look into HBASE.

In Spark, be careful with your job launching -- group the work as best you can, because that start-up penalty is per Spark launch.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by you, if your data is huge(in TB's) it makes sense to use big data platform.

I would suggest you for a hybrid approach.

1. Push all the updates/delta into a table in Hive.
2. find a window hours for batch process to trigger and read the data from hive delta table and update the actual data during batch job.

Now coming to incremental updates using batch job on hive you can find a detailed description on 
http://hadoopgig.blogspot.com/2015/08/incremental-updates-in-hive.html

Hope this helps